# inline-block div expanding its width to the parent div, why?

Tags: html, alignment, behavior, css

As you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yZmP/), the 'innerFooter' div is expanding to it's parent 'footer' despite it's display: inline-block style. I've tried display: table, which WORKS, just wondering while inline-block isn't. Thanks!

***HTML***

```
<div id="footer">
        <div id="innerFooter" class="clearfix alignCenter">
            <ul id="resources">
                <li><a href="#"><b><u>Useful links</u></b></a></li>         
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="social">
                <li><a href="#"><b><u>Get social</u></b></a></li>           
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pinrest</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="contact">
                <li><a href="#"><b><u>Contact us</u></b></a></li>           
                <li><a href="mailto:emailaddress>Email us</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
clearfix{/*Clearfix hack here*/} 
alignCenter{margin: 0 auto}
a{color: inherit}
#footer{
    color: #fff;    
    background-color: #000; 
}
#innerFooter{
    display: inline-block
}
#footer ul{
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
#footer ul > li{
    margin: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle it doesn't seem to be expanding to it's parent.

Comment: It's not an exact simulation as i had clear fix code in live sample, so it's probably overflowing.

Comment: Ok.  It's just you said, 'as you can see in this fiddle', and I couldn't see it.  Reading your comments in the answer below you also want to center the menus.  You can do that like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3yZmP/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the inner footer has floated ellements in it, so its width as, as the summary of all floated ellements' width ("ul") in it.

Comment: The floating isn't needed, i know, but even without it, it won't align to the center.

Comment: without floated ellements, is it expanding?

Comment: Okay, you're right, it was the problem. Do margin not work on inline-block then?

Comment: do you want to center the innerFooter?

Comment: Yeah that's correct! But i don't want to associate a width to the div

Comment: there are many ways

1. keep the ul floated left, then set the innetFooter to table and margin 0 auto, like this  http://jsfiddle.net/3yZmP/5/

2. remove floated left from ul, set them inline-block, then set innerFooter text-align:center, in this case problem, that the children of ul will inherit the rule text-align:center; http://jsfiddle.net/3yZmP/7/

note, that in second example, the innerFoot is expanding to its container, but the uls are centered

Comment: I've tried all of those examples before-hands, just wondered as to why it was expanding. Thanks. I'll probably go for text-align: center. Could i apply that to the UL but not LIs would what work? EDIT: Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: just reset it then, set 

ul{
  text-align:left;
}